# MYSQL & PHP News System

Tags: php, mysql

I have this news system but I can't figure out how to do it like this: `news.php?id=1` then it will output the news id 1. Please help.

I have this so far:

```
<?php
include_once('includes/config.php');
if($id != "") {
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = '$id'");
}
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
if(isset($_GET['id']));
    echo $res['body'];
}
?>
```

It connects to the database (details are stored in the config).

Comment: Where are you defining `$id`?

Comment: Obligatory Suggestion, [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I am really new to php and mysql if someone could guide me through how to make this it would be amazing.

Comment: What are you expecting someone on this site to say that the other sites you've read didn't?

Answer (score 3):

the parameters after the ? in the URL are GET items. Use this:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    // Rest of your code

}
```

Comment: Sorry, but i am really unsure. How am i supposed to make this work. I just watched a tutorial but it wen't to much complicated.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
include_once('includes/config.php');

// see if the id is set in the URL (news.php?id=)
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {

    // get the ID from the URL
    // to make it safer: strip any tags (if it's a number we could cast it to an integer)
    $id = strip_tags($_GET['id']);

    // don't use SELECT *, select only the fields you need
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT body FROM news WHERE id=".mysql_real_escape_string($id));

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        echo $res['body'];
    }
} else {
    echo 'please select an article';
}
```

I would recommend you get away from using the `mysql` functions and use `mysqli` instead, as `mysql` is depreciated and you'll have to learn `mysqli` or `PDO` anyway.

Edit: updated code per comments

Comment: I approve of your attempt to be safer, but why bother with `strip_tags` if you're about to cast to int? So `<blink>182</blink>` becomes `182` rather than `0`...? And since you now know it's an integer, and not a string, `mysql_real_escape_string` is also entirely redundant.

Comment: ^ everything IMSOP says; also, your second call to mysql_query() is wrong (you're passing it a resource, as if it weren't already wrong to be there in the first place), And what if the query fails?

Comment: Thanks guys, updated. I don't want to assume ID is an int (though it probably is), so I removed the casting. I haven't used mysql in years (I use db a class), so I'm pretty rusty :)

Comment: This didn't work. Anyway thanks.

Comment: You have to be more specific to get any results. Did you receive an error message? Did you receive different values from what you were expecting? What didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly lets dissect your current code, to see where your going wrong.

```
<?php
include_once('includes/config.php');
/*
$id is not set anywhere before its used so this if statement will not fire,
if you are attempting to get this $id from a url parameter then you need
to set it first from $_GET['id'] global
*/
if($id != "") {
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = '$id'");
}
/*
This piece of code will fire but where is $sql set?
The mysql_query() function expects a string containing your sql query
so the subsequent lines of code will fail because of this
*/
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    //this block is in the wrong place
    if(isset($_GET['id']));
    echo $res['body'];

}
?>
```

The idea is to get the user input E.G the `$_GET['id']` from the url first, check the value is what your looking for, and then build your query.

As the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated I will show you an example using PDO. Though you can use mysqli, BUT you must **always** use prepared query's whenever *user* values come into contact with your database. This is to stop nasty/accidental sql injections.

```
<?php 
// make the connection to the database using PDO
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=the_awsome_db', 'yourusername', 'password');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $db->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    exit('Sorry there is a problem with the database connection :' . $e->getMessage());
}

// sanitize user input - expecting an int
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

if (is_numeric($id)) {
    // now lets query the database with the param id from the user

    // prepare the query, using a placeholder
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT body, 
                                 some_other_column 
                          FROM news 
                          WHERE id = :placeholder_id');

    // bind the placeholder with the value from the user
    $stmt->bindParam(':placeholder_id', $id);

    // execute the prepared query
    $stmt->execute();

    // fetch the result
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // result not empty - display
    if (!empty($result)) {
        // display your result, use print_r($result) to view the whole result set if unsure
        echo $result['body'];
    } else {
        // no matching id found in the db, do something
        echo 'No results found';
    }
} else {
    // do something as user input is not a number
    exit(header('Location: ./index.php'));
}
?>
```

Hope it helps, if your unsure of getting parameters from the user you may need to look up some more tutorials and get the hang of that first before dabbling with databases and all that good stuff.

Comment: This is way to complicated for me. :s

Comment: @MathiasTangre: when someone gives you this much help, you should make more of an effort in your response. I wonder, since you are getting a large number of downvotes, whether you should do some study on PHP before asking more questions.